# Is there a way to destroy an object from inside of the object itself using Java?

Tags: java

I would like to kill/delete an object from inside of the object itself.

What I need is, for the reference to this object to be null, but I don't want to pass handle to the container. Here is a little code example:

```
class Obj {
     void run(){
         if(true)
             kill(); 
     }
}
class A{
    Obj o;
    void main(){
        o.run();
    }
}
```

After running `o.run()` i would like to `o == null`. Is this possible?

Comment: _o = null_ is a shortcut for suiciding. isn't it? so use it. Then Dr. Garbage Collector will come and will direct it to the graveyard.

Comment: If I got it right, in java you can't change the value of an object using its references because objects pass by value in java.

Comment: From inside of o how can I make o=null? true inside if is for example only

Comment: @Juvanis: I tried. "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable" is what Eclipse thinks of it

Comment: @Juvanis `by typing this = null` - that is just plain wrong. Krever - I recommend you read up more on object lifecycles and garbage collection.

Comment: @Perception I think I know enough about lifecycle. I just need this, because of if(o==null) in other part of app.

Comment: @Krever - I'm sorry, but if you did you would not be asking this question. Java does *not* have the concept of an object 'deleting' itself, and even when there are no longer any references to an object it is not guaranteed that it will be 'deleted' right away.

Comment: @KareemMesbah - Object *references* are passed by value.

Comment: @Perception Maybe i wasnt clear enough. I dont care if object takes memory or not. I just need o == null... "kill" was a metaphor.

Comment: @PM77-1 I am sorry that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't null references to an object from within the object itself, as you want. Here is how you can do it, from the point where you actually have the reference you want to nullify, in scope.

Null the reference once `run()` has completed:

*Edit* Based on feedback...

```
class Obj {
    private boolean killMe = false;
    void run(){
        if(someConditionHere) {
            killMe = true;
        }
    }
    public boolean isKillable() { return killMe; }
}

class A{
    Obj o;
    void main(){
        o.run();
        if(o.isKillable()) {
            o = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made this "true" iside if confusing. Killing the object depends on some condition, which is based on some private members of Obj. So i want to keep it inside Obj. So it is imbpossible...

Comment: Edited to reflect what I think you want. Have the object set its own state during `run()` and interrogate the state once `run()` has returned.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to nullify an object reference from its own member method because an object cannot change references owned by other objects. But you can set all its members field to null: future callers will certainly get a NullPointerException every time they try to access the object. It's even better than suicide if you think about it: the object will stay just alive enough to spread death around him.
If you're lucky you could even get the entire application to kill itself!

The object world would be an awful mess if an object could set all references other objects have already made to it to null, because in OOP an object "owns" its properties (*private* ones anyway) and being able to have them changed from an external source would completely break the encapsulation concept.

Now I am pretty sure it may be handy sometimes (else you wouldn't have asked this question) but if you are programming in java you won't be allowed to do that "out of the box".
The only way is to make your object and the objects holding reference to it agreeing on a common strategy.
Like an isDead method that they should call before trying to do anything else.
You can also implement a PsychologicalSupport object that will proxy access from external objects to your depressive one. When your object wants to die, he just has to notify its Support object about it, and the PS object will stop proxying message, and your object will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
class Obj {
    Obj run(){
        if(someConditionHere) {
            return null;
        }

        return this;
    }
}

class A {
    Obj o;
    void main(){
        o = o.run();
    }
}
```

So there is no need to check for o's internal state in A. And it is more encapsulated.